# phpmailer sends mail without subject and without line breaks

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-7

I use php curl() function to connect from server A to the mail server B to send mail.

```
$body = "body\n\nmore body\nmore body\n\nmore body\n\n";


$post = [
    'sendera' => $sender,
    'sender_name' => $sender_name,
    'subject'   => $subject,
    'body'   => $body,
    'recipient'   => $email,
    'recipient_name' => $name,
    'replyto' => $replyto
];

$ch = curl_init('http://example-mailserver.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Mail is successfully sent but there are 2 problems.

**Problem N 1**

Mail arrive without line breaks, So, all \n are just plain text. Never have had this problem sending mail from the same server. Now when I send with **curl()**, this problem appears. Mail server have **php7** installed. Should this be a **php7** or **curl()** problem?

**Problem N 2**

Mail arrive without subject line, however **$subject** variable exists when script runs, I checked this by sending one more simple mail before calling PHPMailer() function.

So, why PHPMailer ignores **$subject?** I never have had this problem on the server A with php5.

```
mail('my@email', 'check if subject exists', $subject);
```

The mail above arrive with $subject variable. But the mail sent right after that with phpmailer does not have subject line.

```
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->WordWrap   = 0; 
$mail->SingleTo = true;
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->CharSet    = "utf-8";

$mail->From       = $sender;
$mail->FromName   = $sender_name;
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Body       = $body;

$mail->AddAddress($recipient,$recipient_name);
$mail->AddReplyTo(#replyt,"No-Reply");
```

Comment: $mail->Subject = "".$subjects.""; // try this please

Comment: the same problem :(

Comment: Have you tried `<br>` instead

Answer (score 1):

Problem no. 1 might be due to the line breaks you are using. A `\n` is just one of two elements of a full line break, it's a 'newline'. Some mail systems/servers expect a full line break, which is **`\r\n`**, the `\r` in this case is a 'carriage return', the second element of a full line break.

Problem no. 2...first off: what's in your `$subject`?

Comment: $subject is: Confirmar la solicitud de cambio de contraseña

Comment: \r\n does not help, the same problem - plain text

Comment: Sometimes fails when you use accents "áéíóú" or special characters like "ñ". Depends on the machine, config and php config.

Comment: @Wiliam and how do you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Subject problem**

I installed the latest version of phpmailer and not I have Subject.

**Line breaks**

I had **$body** in single quotes:

```
body = 'this is body\r\n\r\nmore body';
```

I changed this to:

```
$body = "this is body\r\n\r\nmore body";
```

And now everything is OK.